# ReactJS How to route only certain requests through http-proxy-middleware

Tags: reactjs, api, http, proxy, middleware

For a project I'm required to access certain APIs that I'm not running locally. As the reader might know, this results in CORS errors. To go around this, I am using http-proxy-middleware. I re-route my requests through https://localhost:3000/. The middleware then adds the required headers to the response coming from the API.

To install the module:

```
npm install http-proxy-middleware
```

My setupProxy.js:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Content-type", "text/html");
    next();
  });
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    next();
  });
  app.use(
    "/api-prefix",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "https://dev.the-domain.com/",
      changeOrigin: true,
      secure: true,
    })
  );
};
```

My requests then look as follows:

```
fetch(`https://localhost:3000/api-prefix/api`, {
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Accept: "application/json",
  },
  mode: "no-cors",
  method: "GET",
}).then( ... )
```

All of that seems to work, but now ALL my paths seem to get prefixed with https://localhost:3000/. This is a piece of code from my header:

```
import logo from "../../../assets/logo.svg";

const Header = ({}) => {

  return (
    <Container className='header_container'>
      <Logo>
        <img alt='logo' src={logo} className='logo-img' />
```

The image cannot be found anymore. Only when I disable the proxy it can be found once again, breaking my API requests.

**My question: How do I ONLY route the API requests through my proxy and leave everything else as it was?**

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. If you don't specify to which prefix a certain `app.use( ... )`  block applies, it applies to everything. I needed to edit my setupProxy.js to apply the first two blocks to /api-prefix as well:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use("/api-prefix", (req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Content-type", "text/html");
    next();
  });
  app.use("/api-prefix", (req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    next();
  });
  app.use(
    "/api-prefix",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "https://dev.the-domain.com/",
      changeOrigin: true,
      secure: true,
    })
  );
};
```